# Background image with chart control / helper in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, charts, helper

when using the chart helper in MVC5, how can I set a background image to the chart?
There is a Chart.BackImage Property in the "original" Chart control.
Is the helper only a small subset or is there a way to assign it with themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template, as follows:

```
string template = @"<Chart>
  <ChartAreas>
     <ChartArea Name=""Default"" BackImage=""/Content/Images/chart.jpg"">
     </ChartArea>
  </ChartAreas>
</Chart>";

var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400, theme: template)
    .AddTitle("Title")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Values",
        xValue: new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" },
        yValues: new[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" })
    .Write();
```

You can also place the `BackImage` attribute in the `Chart` tag:

```
<Chart BackImage=\"/Content/Images/chart.jpg\">...</Chart>
```

Comment: is there a nice way to align the image and/or set transparancy etc.?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander There is the BackImageAlignment property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.backimagealignment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I can use it also with the chart **helper** in the template?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Yes, I think so.

Comment: hmmm, I need to pass a strong type of ChartImageAlignmentStyle in template? Does not work for me

Comment: @FalcoAlexander I think you should open another question, maybe someone will give some advices about ChartImageAlignmentStyle.

Comment: I did. but no response... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105015/chart-control-helper-in-mvc