# chart control helper in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts

when using the chart helper in MVC5, how can I set properties that are hidden from the "original" Web.UI. chart control? Is the helper only a small subset or is there a way to assign it with themes?
Some properties like BackImage can be set via template like shown here: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35087744/backgound-image-with-chart-control-helper-in-razor/35089784?noredirect=1#comment57930557_35089784)

When should I use normal Control and when helper?

this is the "classic" way in the controller:

```
 var myChartBack = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
 myChartBack.BackImage = "/Pics/Pic.jpg";
 myChartBack.XY=Z (FullFeatureSetofControl etc.)
 [...]
```

Comment: Where do you check the inheritence?

Comment: Ok. Would be nicer if you could check it like this http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Comment: yes true. I'm still seaching for doc about the template/theme. some properties of the class are accepted, others not